# Stop build and display message with Build Events

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, cmd

I am using the Build Events with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 to copy some files into the `$(TargetDir)`. How can I stop the build if a particular file isn't found. Currently I have something like:

```
IF EXIST somefile ( 
ECHO true 
) ELSE (
ECHO false 
)
```

With displays `true` and `false` to the build output dialog as appropriate but I'd like to replace `ECHO false` with

```
ELSE (
ECHO somefile was not found
exit
)
```

Where `exit` stops the Visual Studio from building the project and `somefile was not found` is the last message displayed in the output console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forcing visual studio to stop the build it needs only to set the errorlevel

```
IF NOT EXIST somefile (
  echo somefile was not found
  echo ERROR: This will be displayed in the error list of VS
  exit /b 1
)
```

Comment: This `exit` command does not stop Visual Studio from building the project when issued as a pre-built event.

Comment: Giving an errorlevel makes Visual Studio complain about the pre-build step itself `Error 1 The command "IF NOT EXIST somefile1 (
echo somefile was not found
exit 3 
)" exited with code 3. ` this seems more like a hack.

Comment: The exit doesn't stop it, but with an errorlevel it should. Additionally you can add some error output, that will be displayed in the error list, not only in the build output

Comment: I always use a prebuild.bat file, VS reports then the error for the batch file (like it would report an error while linking) `Fehler 2 error MSB3073: Der Befehl "D:\Projekte\xyz\Tools\PreBuild.bat
:VCEnd" wurde mit dem Code 2 beendet. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 103`

Comment: Okay that'll work.. but what about the macros like `$(SolutionDir)` ect.. I'd like to use those in the `prebuild.bat` script if possible.

Comment: You can't access them directly but as batch param. My prelink event is `$(ProjectDir)\PreBuild.bat "$(SolutionDir)"`. I use the quotes to avoid problems with spaces or special characters when accessing the `%1` parameter from batch