# Visual Studio 2017: Cancel build in pre build event

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I can't seem to find whether it is possible in Visual Studio to cancel a build by checking something in a pre build event. Is this possible? If so: how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop build and display message with Build Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360054/stop-build-and-display-message-with-build-events)

Answer (score 3):

I can use `exit /b 1`.  It intentionally causes the pre-build event to fail by setting the %errorlevel% to 1, stopping the build.  The error message is not great.