# MS Visual Studio subproject compilation prebuilt events IF condition error

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, pre-build-event

My solution has two projects: c++ dll and c# web.
Dll project has **pre-built event** like this

```
IF 2 == 1
(
   echo ERROR: Dll building error
)
```

And, obviously, this condition not interrupts building process and it finishes with success, if I run it for dll project.

But..
the Web project depends on the dll and therefore  uilds it, in turn, by MSBUILD.exe command in it own pre-build event. That is, as a result, pre-build parent (MSBUILD for web) following by nested pre-build childs (IF for dll).
.  And if I try to build web project, it interrupts with message **Dll building error** (from the dll project pre-built event) after child dll project by MSBUILD.exe (in web pre-built event) has built **with success!!!** - result dll file has appeared in output dir!.

What it's means? Child pre-build event conditions incorrectly interrupts parent build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're misusing MSBuild. The proper way to handle "subprojects" is to use a Solution. In this solution, you have both projects, and a project dependency from the web project on the DLL. You build the solution, and that's one MSBuild command. Therefore, the C# web project does not need to start another MSBuild command.

MSBuild, when using a solution file, sees the real dependencies and handles build failures correctly. Note that a "echo ERROR" in a pre-build event is just text on a screen, not a build failure. [You'll need to `exit /b 1` the pre-build step to stop the build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360054/stop-build-and-display-message-with-build-events)

Comment: Yes, sorry, forget it.. Real pre-built condition is IF 2 == 1
(
   echo ERROR: Dll building error; exit /b 1
), but I changed algo to use dependencies, not msbuild in pre-build event, thanks